# optimize piece-wise constant function

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am wondering if MATLAB has a solver that is able to maximize a multivariate piece-wise constant function.

When I use the naïve optimize function, it gets stuck at the initial value since it's constant within a neighborhood of the initial value.

Comment: before you go trying something different, have you tried just starting with a different initial value.

Comment: I'm not sure that maximizing a piece-wise constant function is really do-able... from an optimization point of view. Maybe some sort of line search or Monte Carlo (random guesses) method would serve you well.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide your objective function and the accompanying constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow a more elaborated version of @Frederick suggestion. A simple stochastic approach, but not exactly a linear search because of the multivariate characteristic: [simulated annealing](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/simulated-annealing.html)